# OracleSQL - calculate difference (and return in %growth) in data between sysdate and sysdate-7 days ago in a (big) table with lots of timestamps

Tags: sql, oracle

(OracleSQL) We have our own created application that tracks storage usage in MB. I'd like a query that, without manual changes (as we will integrate this query in our application, which will automatically periodically run this query) can calculate the difference of storage for the past week since sysdate. Bonuspoints if we can calculate this difference in %growth too!

The table we use has automatically collected information on storage. It checks every X minutes (I honestly am not sure how often, the data seems rather random, but it's at least hourly and often more often than that).

| Client_Name | Check_Timestamp | Total_MB | Used_MB | Remaining_MB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Client1 | 03/28/2022 15:04:37 | 52280 | 20533 | 34747 |
| Client1 | 03/28/2022 14:01:20 | 52280 | 20421 | 31859 |
| Client1 | 03/21/2022 14:01:20 | 51090 | 20300 | 30790 |
| Client1 | 03/21/2022 13:49:20 | 51090 | 20121 | 30969 |
| Client2 | 03/28/2022 15:34:17 | 52280 | 20533 | 34747 |
| Client2 | 03/28/2022 14:20:22 | 52280 | 20421 | 31859 |
| Client2 | 03/21/2022 14:09:54 | 51090 | 20300 | 30790 |
| Client2 | 03/21/2022 13:32:03 | 51090 | 20121 | 30969 |

My attempts have failed miserably this far.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share table definitions, and a minimal sample of data, with desired results?  And, of course, your attempt so far!, because stackoverflow is not a free code writing servers, (and also not free for "enough bonus points")

Comment: Of course! However as a (obvious) headsup I'm not quite good with any of this just yet - the application was coded by my colleague and I'm just a student of SQL. I was asked to find out about this query by my colleague. My attempts are..... very sad, I am ashamed to share them honestly. Many of them were trying to understand functions I'd forgotten, fooling around with window functions and working out why GROUP BY refused to 'work'.... I was under the impression stackoverflow is a place where people gather and exchange knowledge on a voluntary/fun basis. Sample data: editing main post now!

Comment: If it is too much asked to make an entire query, that is of course completely fine, I'd much appreciate even any hints or advice into what direction I should go in.

Comment: Can you edit this [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=0059b765a4cec9b33eab307852898656) into a working one ?

Comment: The measurements seem to be taken at random points in time (meaning, not at exact times, such as at exactly hh:00:00 if taken hourly, or perhaps at hh:45:00 if taken hourly at 45 minutes on the hour, or exactly at hh:mi:00 where mi is divisible by 5, if taken every 5 minutes, etc.) As such, what do "sysdate" and "sysdate - 7 days" mean in this context? For example: are you looking for the latest timestamp <= sysdate and the latest timestamp <= sysdate - 7 (separately for each client)? Or perhaps <= trunc(sysdate) and <= trunc(sysdate) - 7? You need to clarify the task in this regard.

Comment: yes they're more random than they're not, which is what poses the problem also. By sysdate-7 I meant more, Today compared to 7 days ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something to get you started. This query will find the most recent entry for each client (comparing to SYSDATE), and the most recent entry as of exactly seven days before SYSDATE. You might need to wrap SYSDATE within TRUNC if you want to compare to TRUNC(SYSDATE) instead.

You can make this into a subquery and do any additional computations you need, such as increase in MB and in percentage points. That part is trivial; if you can't add it yourself, perhaps you shouldn't be working on such problems in the first place.

Since I am running this on 04/20/2022 at 10:26 AM my time, your sample data isn't relevant. I used this instead (only relevant columns):

```
create table storage_tracking
( client_name     varchar2(15)
, check_timestamp timestamp 
, used_mb number
);

alter session set nls_timestamp_format = 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

insert into storage_tracking
  select 'Client1', '04/20/2022 10:04:37',   20533 from dual union all
  select 'Client1', '04/19/2022 04:01:20',   20421 from dual union all
  select 'Client1', '04/13/2022 14:01:20',   20300 from dual union all
  select 'Client1', '04/13/2022 08:49:20',   20121 from dual union all
  select 'Client2', '04/20/2022 10:24:17',   20533 from dual union all
  select 'Client2', '04/20/2022 08:20:22',   20421 from dual union all
  select 'Client2', '04/14/2022 14:09:54',   20300 from dual union all
  select 'Client2', '04/12/2022 07:32:03',   20121 from dual
;

commit;
```

Query and output:

```
select client_name,
       max(case when check_timestamp <= sysdate - 7 
                then check_timestamp end) as week_earlier,
       max(used_mb) keep (dense_rank last order by case 
                when check_timestamp <= sysdate - 7
                then check_timestamp end nulls first) as used_mb_week_earlier,
       max(case when check_timestamp <= sysdate
                then check_timestamp end) as now,
       max(used_mb) keep (dense_rank last order by case
                when check_timestamp <= sysdate
                then check_timestamp end nulls first) used_mb_now
from   storage_tracking
group  by client_name
;

CLIENT_NAME     WEEK_EARLIER        USED_MB_WEEK_EARLIER NOW                 USED_MB_NOW
--------------- ------------------- -------------------- ------------------- -----------
Client1         04/13/2022 08:49:20                20121 04/20/2022 10:04:37       20533
Client2         04/12/2022 07:32:03                20121 04/20/2022 10:24:17       20533
```

Comment: This query is wonderful. I may not be an expert indeed but thankfully I did still have the ability to edit the query for our purposes, so it's working like a charm now thanks to your work on this. Maybe one day I'll be able to come to Stackoverflow and answer questions so effectively myself too. Until then I may have to rely on experts like you again in the future..! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the values for a day and want the maximum total and used and the minimum remaining then:

```sql
SELECT t.*,
       ROUND((total_mb / total_mb_last_week) * 100 - 100, 2) AS percent_total_growth,
       ROUND((used_mb / used_mb_last_week) * 100 - 100, 2) AS percent_used_growth,
       ROUND((remaining_mb / remaining_mb_last_week) * 100 - 100, 2) AS percent_remaining_growth
FROM   (
  SELECT client_name,
         TRUNC(Check_timestamp) AS check_day,
         MAX(total_mb) AS total_mb,
         MAX(used_mb) AS used_mb,
         MIN(remaining_mb) AS remaining_mb,
         MAX(MAX(total_mb)) OVER (
           PARTITION BY Client_Name
           ORDER BY TRUNC(Check_Timestamp)
           RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '7' DAY PRECEDING AND INTERVAL '7' DAY PRECEDING
         ) AS total_mb_last_week,
         MAX(MAX(used_mb)) OVER (
           PARTITION BY Client_Name
           ORDER BY TRUNC(Check_Timestamp)
           RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '7' DAY PRECEDING AND INTERVAL '7' DAY PRECEDING
         ) AS used_mb_last_week,
         MAX(MIN(remaining_mb)) OVER (
           PARTITION BY Client_Name
           ORDER BY TRUNC(Check_Timestamp)
           RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '7' DAY PRECEDING AND INTERVAL '7' DAY PRECEDING
         ) AS remaining_mb_last_week
  FROM   table_name
  GROUP BY client_name, TRUNC(Check_Timestamp)
) t
WHERE check_day = DATE '2022-03-28';
```

Will, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Client_Name, Check_Timestamp, Total_MB, Used_MB, Remaining_MB) AS
SELECT 'Client1', DATE '2022-03-28' + INTERVAL '15:04:37' HOUR TO SECOND, 52280, 20533, 34747 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Client1', DATE '2022-03-28' + INTERVAL '14:01:20' HOUR TO SECOND, 52280, 20421, 31859 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Client1', DATE '2022-03-21' + INTERVAL '14:01:20' HOUR TO SECOND, 51090, 20300, 30790 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Client1', DATE '2022-03-21' + INTERVAL '13:49:20' HOUR TO SECOND, 51090, 20121, 30969 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Client2', DATE '2022-03-28' + INTERVAL '15:34:17' HOUR TO SECOND, 52280, 20533, 34747 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Client2', DATE '2022-03-28' + INTERVAL '14:20:22' HOUR TO SECOND, 52280, 20421, 31859 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Client2', DATE '2022-03-21' + INTERVAL '14:09:54' HOUR TO SECOND, 51090, 20300, 30790 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Client2', DATE '2022-03-21' + INTERVAL '13:32:03' HOUR TO SECOND, 51090, 20121, 30969 FROM DUAL;
```

Output:

> | CLIENT_NAME | CHECK_DAY | TOTAL_MB | USED_MB | REMAINING_MB | TOTAL_MB_LAST_WEEK | USED_MB_LAST_WEEK | REMAINING_MB_LAST_WEEK | PERCENT_TOTAL_GROWTH | PERCENT_USED_GROWTH | PERCENT_REMAINING_GROWTH |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | Client1 | 28-MAR-22 | 52280 | 20533 | 31859 | 51090 | 20300 | 30790 | 2.33 | 1.15 | 3.47 |
> | Client2 | 28-MAR-22 | 52280 | 20533 | 31859 | 51090 | 20300 | 30790 | 2.33 | 1.15 | 3.47 |

If you want the values for the current day (which you have not provided data for) then change the last line to:

```sql
WHERE  check_day = TRUNC(SYSDATE);
```

Or, if you want to get the values for all days in the database then remove that `WHERE` clause.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2bf1af36aedc2e1a92a330d2c8729c41)*

Comment: This is really great, thank you!!! That's returning so much beautiful information, it got me all excited for this project all over again. Thank you :)